# How to get and echo the "Alternative Layout" value from the Joomla! MENU module in index.php (template)?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I need to get the value of the "Alternative Layout" for my MENU module:

Example:

Alternative Layout = layout1

I need the value "layout1" to be echoed inside my template file (index.php)

is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have to add to your template is:

```
<?php
        jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'menu', 'Footer menu' );

        $moduleParams = new JRegistry();
        $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
        $layout = $moduleParams->get('layout');
        echo $layout;
?>
```

You have to set the type of the module and the title at:

> getModule( 'menu', 'Footer menu' );

Comment: Here's what I did:

`<?php
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'menu', 'Main Menu' );

$moduleParams = new JRegistry();
$moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
$layout = $moduleParams->get('mainmenu');
echo $layout;
?>`

Just want to make it clear, so the "menu" is the module type right? and "Main Menu" is the title of the menu under Module Manager, then "mainmenu" is the name of the alternative layout.

Comment: seem ok, does it echo the layout name?

Comment: Please try to set `$layout = $moduleParams->get('mainmenu');` to `$layout = $moduleParams->get('layout');`.